# setdefault() not inserting key with default for nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, setdefault

The dictionary structure is:

```
storage = {}   
storage['first'] = {}   
storage['middle'] = {}  
storage['last'] = {}
```

The first insertion made to this dictionary is:

```
me = 'Magnus Lie Hetland'   
storage['first']['Magnus'] = [me]  
storage['middle']['Lie'] = [me] 
storage['last']['Hetland'] = [me]
```

Then the following statements are executed:

```
my_sister = 'Anne Lie Hetland'
storage['first'].setdefault('Anne', []).append(my_sister)
```

As per the documentation `setdefault` should insert the key `'Anne'` with a value `[] (New Empty list)` and then it should append `my_sister`.
So why it is appending `my_sister` to the pre-existing list and not creating new list.

Comment: what do you think the output should be?

Comment: Is `{'first': {'Magnus': ['Magnus Lie Hetland'], 'Anne': ['Anne Lie Hetland']}, 'middle': {'Lie': ['Magnus Lie Hetland']}, 'last': {'Hetland': ['Magnus Lie Hetland']}}` something else than you expected?

Comment: @hchw  `storage['middle']['Lie']' should give output
'['Magnus Lie Hetland'] , [ 'Anne Lie Hetland']` and not a single list containing both names.

Comment: It doesn't result in a single list containing both names. See e.g. the comment from @Błotosmętek.

Comment: When I run your code I get what you expect!

Comment: Your code above appends your sister only to `storage['first']['Anne']`, why do you expect her to be added to `storage['middle']['Lie']`? There is nothing in your code to cause it.